# How can i search the numbers in order?

Tags: vba, excel, fill

My problem is the as follows:

- I have 3 columns and 20 rows, that contains numbers.
- There is a line with numbers between 1 to 20 in order crescente, the other cells contains bigger numbers then 100 or whatever.

My **homework** is that I have to write a VBA code which fill color the cells that contains the line. This way i going to have a "colorful snake" from the cells that contains the **numbers between 1 to 20**.

- Of course, the starting number cell is "A1"
- the ending cell can be anywhere in the area "A1:C20"
- the substance is the colored cells must have follow the numbers in order cresence!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. "Please give me code so I can finish my homework" is not the way this platform works. I you want to get help, vou've do show own efforts.

Comment: You should start by watching [Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).   You should be able to loop through all the cells by the end of the video.  If you get stuck, post your code and you'll get plenty of help.

Comment: _"the substance is the colored cells must have follow the numbers in order cresence!"_: I guess the very goal of your homework is making you think about this sentence, namely its final part. After solving this issue you could code in a more effective way

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub MeykEhYewowSnakhey()
        Dim r, c
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For r = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                If ws.Cells(r, c).Value < 100 Then
                    ws.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Try that.

Comment: The OP stated that the cells were in `Range("A1:C20")`. You have no way of know what the actual UsedRange.  You should also target values "between 1 to 20".  If the worksheet is setup like the image, your code would color every blank cell from `A1:G17`.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much more efficient way to solve this but this is my solution.

```
Sub Snake()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mySnake As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer

    Set wbk = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    x = 1
    y = 1
    With ws
        For mySnake = 1 To 20
            If .Cells(x, y) = mySnake Then
                .Cells(x, y).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                'Check cell below
                If .Cells(x + 1, y) = mySnake + 1 Then
                    x = x + 1
                'Check cell to right
                ElseIf .Cells(x, y + 1) = mySnake + 1 Then
                    y = y + 1
                'Check cells to left if y <> 1
                ElseIf y <> 1 Then
                    If .Cells(x, y - 1) = mySnake + 1 Then
                        y = y - 1
                    End If
                'Check cells above if x <> 1
                ElseIf x <> 1 Then
                    If .Cells(x - 1, y) = mySnake + 1 Then
                        x = x - 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next mySnake
    End With
End Sub
```